# if there is a limit imposed by the standard library for threads count used by subprocess opened by system() command ? c++

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

I  use thread lib to create multiple thread for my c++ program, and I call a executable program in each thread by using system() command. The executable program is multithreading itself.

so I want to ask if there is a limit for threads counts for the executable program called by system() could used in each thread , If there are some rule in thread library or standard library to limit the usage of thread for sub excutable program called by `system()`command？

Above is my question, If you have any question , you could read my code example below.

please ignore the progress_bar.h, it is nothing to do with my question, it's a head file which is used to show progress bar.

parallel.h is like:

```
#ifndef parallel_h
#define parallel_h

#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>

#include "progress_bar.h"

//simple thread pool implementation
//updateFun should be thread-safe!
template <class T>
void processInParallel(const std::vector<T>& scheduledTasks,  
                       std::function<void(const T&)> updateFun,
                       size_t maxThreads, bool progressBar)
{
    if (scheduledTasks.empty()) return;

    std::atomic<size_t> jobId(0);
    ProgressPercent progress(scheduledTasks.size());
    if (progressBar) progress.advance(0);

    auto threadWorker = [&jobId, &scheduledTasks, &updateFun,
                         &progress, progressBar]()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            size_t expected = 0;
            while(true)
            {
                expected = jobId;
                if (jobId == scheduledTasks.size())
                {
                    return;
                }
                if (jobId.compare_exchange_weak(expected, expected + 1))
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            updateFun(scheduledTasks[expected]);
            if (progressBar) progress.advance();
        }
    };

    std::vector<std::thread> threads(std::min(maxThreads,
                                              scheduledTasks.size()));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < threads.size(); ++i)
    {
        threads[i] = std::thread(threadWorker);
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < threads.size(); ++i)
    {
        threads[i].join();
    }
}

#endif /* parallel_h */
```

in main.cpp

```
#include "parallel.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <function>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    std::vector<int> jobids = {1,2,3,4,5};
    std::function<void(const int& jobid)>testfunc = [](const int& jobid)
    {
        system("Call another executable program here!");
    };
    size_t threadnum = 5;
    processInParallel(testfunc, jobids, threadnum, true);
         
}
```

can anyone give me an answer?

Comment: You should never use `system()` - that function is a security nightmare.

Comment: @JaMiT thanks for you reply, I don't mean limited by compute resource, I want to ask if there some rules in c++ thread library which set a limit for the thread count each thread could used.

Comment: ulimit -T gives the user limit of threads

Comment: @JesperJuhl yes, you are right, but sometime, if I want to use some function from a software written by c++, the simplest way is to using system(), or you have to extract some code from the software(if this software is open source ), or using the code of the software as library, it obviously much more complicate.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main limits for number of threads in Linux.

One is a limit for total amount of threads in system that can be checked in:
`/proc/sys/kernel/threads-max`. This limit is system-wide and it gives you insight how many threads can be run by kernel.
It's worth to look also on `/proc/sys/vm/max_map_count` as it contains information about how many virtual memory areas a process can own.

The second one is indirect limit connected with amount of virtual memory:

`number of threads = total virtual memory / (stack size*1024*1024)`

As you can create new threads with custom value of stack size this limit can vary. Increasing process virtual memory or decreasing stack size for new threads can allow you to run more threads within single process. Check `ulimit` for more information.

If your distribution is systemd-based you'd like to look also on UserTasksMax setting.